# nanoFramework ESP32 Not waking up after sleep with Keypad

Tags: c#, sleep, esp32, keypad, nanoframework

I am doing a project with a numeric keypad, an ESP32 programmed in nanoFramework (CoreLibrary 1.9.0 p5, Esp32 1.3.2 p9).
Now I want to wake up the controller with a keypress on one of the buttons.
The code for handling the matrix works fine, buttons are responsive and working:

```
var row4 = controller.OpenPin(32);
row4.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
...
var col3 = controller.OpenPin(12);
col3.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullDown);
```

Before going to sleep i redefine the drive modes to have one pin at 3.3V:

```
Sleep.EnableWakeupByPin(Sleep.WakeupGpioPin.Pin32, 1);
col3.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.OutputOpenDrainPullUp);
Sleep.StartLightSleep();
```

So the ESP32 goes into sleep as expected, but I cannot wake it up with pin 32.

What I've tried:

- Pin numbering seems a bit strange when it comes to RTC-pins. Pin32 seems to be RTC-Pin9. But the `WakeupGpioPin`-enum only contains normal GPIO numbers.
- Tried to swap the two, Pin12 as WakeupPin and Pin32 as Pullup.
- Externally pulling the pin high or low - no effect
- The "level" parameter in `EnableWakeupByPin` seems to be the voltage level and 1 beeing HIGH, according to the [espressif Docs](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html#_CPPv428esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup10gpio_num_ti). However, I also tried 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pin numbering is per the Espressif documentation. You don't need to configure the GPIO pins before the call to EnableWakeupByPin unless used by application.

I have tested this and It looks like the Sleep.EnableWakeupByPin() is not working. We will look into the cause and get it fixed.

Try using the Sleep.EnableWakeupByMultiPins(). I have tested and that is working.

```
Sleep.EnableWakeupByMultiPins(Sleep.WakeupGpioPin.Pin32, Sleep.WakeupMode.AnyHigh);
```

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks Adrian. Is there an Issue on GitHub already?